# Eclipse TM Terminal: ESP32 serial terminal

Tags: eclipse, terminal, serial-port, line-endings, esp32

I try to use Eclipse TM Terminal to communicate with my ESP-32. However, at some point it starts not shifting to line beginning. It looks like this:
[image].

Changing `Line ending for UART output` don't change anything. How can I get this working?

UPD: everything did worked just fune, but after reconnecting device I get same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

The output looks like only the LineFeed character is getting through (Character 10).  Carriage Return is Character 13, and appears not to be getting through.  You do need both.  If you do have CR and LF at the end of each text string, something must be stripping out the CR.  Either that our you are getting off by a bit and the last bit is now at the beginning of the next 8 bit set.  What is the handshake method being used?  For that matter, what is the port setup?  Baud Rate? Parity?

Comment: This is no valid argument, as `\n` has been widely used as meaning 'newline', and not 'linefeed' (in all Linux OSes for example). From what I can tell, the Eclipse terminal is just a buggy quick hack as it has no configuration, and does other things wrong too (e.g. the 'move cursor left' `\b` stops at the left column instead of wrapping around)